# line space between h2 element and paragraph

Tags: html, css

So I have an `<h2>` element and a `<p>` right below it and I'd like to space them out a little bit. Currently I'm just using a `<br>` between them but I was wondering if there's a way to do it in CSS? It can be applied to all the `<h2>` and `<p>` elements on my page. Thanks!

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp

Comment: You can use add a margin at the bottom - see this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_margin-bottom.asp.

Comment: Consider using the `margin-top` property (e.g.  `margin-top: 2px`) on the second element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can control line-spacing in one HTML tag only. So if you have

```
<h2 style="line-spacing:40px;">Hello World</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
```

It will only affect the `<h2>` "Hello World" and not the `<p>` tag with the text Lorem Ipsum. You need to give the  a margin-bottom such as this:

```
<h2 style="margin-bottom:40px;">Hello World</h2>
<p>Lorem ipsum</p>
```